# Field checker in org.test.api.controller.CheckerController required a bean of type 'org.test.api.checker.Checker' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I get the following error when running the Spring application from IntellijIDEA.

```
2017-04-20 18:20:50.645 ERROR 28680 --- [main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field checker in org.test.api.controller.CheckerController required a bean of type 'org.test.api.checker.Checker' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.test.api.checker.Checker' in your configuration.
```

However, I have the class `Checker` in the path `org.test.api.checker.Checker`.

This is a sample code of the class `CheckerController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/{clientId}")
public class CheckerController {

    @Autowired
    Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Checker")
    Checker checker;


    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Context.class, new ContextEditor());
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/{userId}/{sessionId}/check", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CheckResults check(@PathVariable String clientId,
                                 @PathVariable String userId,
                                 @PathVariable String sessionId) {
    CheckRequest checkRequest = new CheckRequest(CheckRequest.TYPE_1, clientId, userId, sessionId);
    this.validateRequest(checkRequest);
    return checker.check(checkRequest);
}

}
```

The class `Checker`:

```
public interface Checker {

    CheckResults check(CheckRequest request);

}
```

How to fix this issue?

**UPDATE:**

```
@Service
public class CheckerImpl implements Checker {

    @Override
    public CheckResults check(CheckRequest request)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytestapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spark.version>1.6.1</spark.version>
        <es.version>2.2.0</es.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.spullara.mustache.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${es.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-tdb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: post your Checker class and the configuration classes.

Comment: @shi: I posted the class `Checker`. What do you mean by configuration classes?

Comment: I see Checker is an interface, do you have any implementation of this? By configuration classes I meant the class where you have declared spring configuration or are you using xml config?

Comment: @shi: Ok, I posted the implementation class `CheckerImpl` and also `pom.xml`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are autowiring by `@Qualifier("Checker")`, define bean name inside `@Service` of your CheckerImpl class.

```
@Service("Checker")
public class CheckerImpl implements Checker {

    @Override
    public CheckResults check(CheckRequest request)
    {
       // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case I get another error: `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/Web`. What does it mean?

Comment: please share your spring boot configuration file

Comment: I only have `pom.xml`. I do not have any other specification files.

Comment: pom.xml is maven build file not spring configuration file. Looking for the files where you have @SpringBootApplication, or the main class from where you are running it.

Comment: Ok, my main class: `import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}`

Comment: I would suggest to post all your classes.

Comment: I reimported the project to IntellijIdea and now it runs well. It seems that I had some old files in the folder `.idea`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

original error was due to the use of invalid qualifier `@Qualifier("Checker")`. No bean for id "Checker" is present in the context. Since there's only one suitable implementation using additional `@Qualifier` is useless.

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge of Spring is a bit limited. Could you please specify what do you mean by `No bean for id "Checker" is present in the context`? Where should I specify it? I have the abstract class `Checker` and its implementation class `CheckerImpl`. In `CheckerController` I define `@Autowired
    @Qualifier("Checker")`, which I understand as the requirement to use the class `Checker`.

Comment: The Qualifier annotation is no requirement. It is only necessary if you have multiple beans of the same type, to distinguish them by name. If you want to keep it, you have to give the CheckerImpl bean the same name `@Service("Checker")`